# jquery ajax put request returns 400 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, rest

The following ajax is being responded with a 400 error (bad request):

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({"DeliveryKey":"37507","Produkttyp":"ES 95  120","Abgabemenge":"12","Bonnummer":"","Vorpeilung":"12","Gesamtangabe":"24","NachpeilungVolume":"","PumpenstandVolume":""});
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    processData: false,
    url: rootURL + 'allproducts/product/' + deliveryKey, // jsonObj.DeliveryKey
    data: jsonData,
    success:  function(data){
        alert("Data PUT-Request successfully!");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Fehler in der Methode putProduktInDatabase()");
        }
});
```

Here is the consuming sides code:

```
@Path("/allproducts")
 public class ProduktModellResource {

 ProduktModellDAO produktModellDAO = new ProduktModellDAO();

 @PUT @Path("product/{deliveryKey}")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 public boolean putProduktInDatabase(ProduktModell produkt)
 {
    return produktModellDAO.putProduktInDatabase(produkt);
 }
}
```

and here is the screenshot of the requests header in Google Chrome:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

On the server side I return "true" or "false" depending on whether the desired function was called or an exception has been thrown. Is that allowed or should I response only with a JSON?

Comment: you missed `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @ling.s it wont hurt AJAX So badly

Comment: The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers

Comment: @Pilot what do you mean by value? you can see the full link in the first line under "Request URL"

Comment: @ling.s running the above code with a "POST" request also results as a bad request.

Comment: Running the code as a "POST" or "PUT" in Firefox and Safari results as "Method not allowed", while Chrome says bad request

Answer (score 0):

From official Jquery [site](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> type (default: 'GET')
>   Type: String
>   The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request 
>   methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

You better do not use PUT type or... "you gonna have a bad time" ! :)

Comment: as I already mentioned in the previous comments, changing the type to "POST" and running it also results as a bad request, so I really do not know what I am missing

Comment: Are you sure that URL is 100% correct? I bet URL is bad. Try the same JS code on different route (the simplest - the best) like /index.

If JS code is correct you've got bad ROUTING or bad URL params.


PS: End when changed PUT into POST, You've done it in js file and controller?

Comment: rootURL is definitely correct as it is used by some "GET" requests that are executed before this request. If my backend side were incorrect and the request weren't able to reach the backend because of  wrong paths, everybody would see that, as I provided the code for both ajax request and the code handling it